# SSRS 2008: Using StDevP from multiple fields / Combining multiple fields in general

Tags: expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I'd like to calculate the standard deviation over two fields from the same dataset.

example:
MyFields1 = 10, 10
MyFields2 = 20

What I want now, is the standard deviation for (10,10,20), the expected result is 4.7

In SSRS I'd like to have something like this:
=StDevP(Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value)

Unfortunately this isn't possible, since (Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value) returns a single value and not a list of values. Is there no way to combine two fields from the same dataset into some kind of temporary dataset?

The only solutions I have are:

1. To create a new Dataset that contains all values from both fields. But this is very annoying because I need about twenty of those and I have six report parameters that need to filter every query. => It's probably getting very slow and annoying to maintain.
2. Write the formula by hand. But I don't really know how yet. StDevP is not that trivial to me. This is how I did it with Avg which is mathematically simpler:
   =(SUM(Fields!MyField1.Value)+SUM(Fields!MyField2.Value))/2 
   found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/7ff43716-2529-4240-a84d-42ada929020e

Btw. I know that it's odd to make such a calculation, but this is what my customer wants and I have to deliver somehow.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTDevP is standard deviation.
Such expression works fine for me 
`=StDevP(Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value)` but it's deviation from one value (Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value) **which is always 0.**
you can look here for formula:
[standard deviation (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

I believe that you need to calculate this for some group (or full dataset), to do this you need set in the CTDevP your scope:

```
=StDevP(Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value, "MyDataSet1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize that (Fields!MyField1.Value + Fields!MyField2.Value) is a single value. I was hoping to get all values from both fields in some kind of temporary dataset. I changed my question a bit, it was a bit confusing.

Comment: I suppose that you can't do such combination of datasets. The only way is to use UNION ALL in SQL level or implement using Custom Code your own formula.

Comment: I did it with a UNION ALL in a stored procedure. It works so far I'm only a bit worried about the performance, since the query has many conditions (from ssrs parameters) and inner functions (to split multi valued parameters). I also tried it with custom code, but the only solution I found to pass all values from a field into the custom code function, goes trough a hidden multi valued parameter. It's a terrible hack, but if the performance becomes a problem I might try it that way too. Thanks for your help.